# Material-UI global overrides: How to target inner elements?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, jss

I have created a global style for a Material UI Switch and would like to override styles of the `track`, `thumb`, etc for the small variation.  I'm able to target the root element using the `sizeSmall` class however I think I'm taking the wrong approach to modifying the inner elements.

I'm not sure if I should be using something like `& $sizeSmall` inside of `track` or vice versa.

Code sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-vkdsh?file=/theme.js

Relevant theme override:

```
MuiSwitch: {
      root: {
        width: 96,
        height: 40,
        padding: 0,
        margin: 8,
        borderRadius: 48,
        boxShadow:
          "inset -3px -3px 7px #FFFFFF, inset 3px 3px 7px rgba(156, 156, 156, 0.48);"
      },
      sizeSmall: {
        width: 60,
        height: 18,
        borderRadius: 9,
        padding: 0
      },
      switchBase: {
        marginTop: 7,
        marginLeft: 12,
        padding: 1,
        "&$checked, &$colorPrimary$checked, &$colorSecondary$checked": {
          transform: "translateX(46px)",
          color: "#fff",
          "& + $track": {
            opacity: 1,
            border: "none",
            background:
              "linear-gradient(172.54deg, #2B8CFF -34.02%, #0354CE 124.23%);"
          }
        }
      },
      thumb: {
        width: 24,
        height: 24,
        boxShadow:
          "2px 1px 8px rgba(185, 185, 185, 0.3), inset 0px -1px 1px rgba(95, 95, 95, 0.4);"
      },
      track: {
        margin: "auto 16px",
        height: 8,
        borderRadius: 9,
        border: "1px solid #D3D4D5",
        backgroundColor: "#fafafa",
        opacity: 1,
        transition:
          "background-color 300ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms,border 300ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms"
      }
    },
```

[image: Full and small versions of switch]

Comment: Please paste the relevant code into your question. Code Sandboxes change or go away.

Comment: I believe the codesandbox is frozen but I've added the current theme override and result image.

Answer (score 0):

[this is](https://material-ui.com/api/switch/#css) the CSS classes and one of them is `track`, you can use that to override and that will change all over. If you want to target a separate element you need to use `classes` prop and target the `track` class

```
<Switch classes={{ root: someClass, track: trackClass}}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check how material-ui handles this [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/Switch/Switch.js) and have more accurate approach to what u're trying to do :)